# How to initialize map of byte arrays?

Tags: c++

How can I initialize a map where the keys are strings and the values are pairs of data (array of bytes) and sizes?

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

std::map<std::string, std::pair<char*, size_t>> my_map = {
    {"key1", {{0xE2, 0x82, 0xAC}, 3}}
};
```

The above code doesn't compile.

Comment: Not doable with C-style array. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @user2864740 Yeah, I meant to replace `std::pair<char*, size_t>` with `std::vector` (since that's what this pair seems to represent). Sorry for being unclear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code supposes you'll store char pointers in the `std::pair`. Char pointer is not the same as char array, although char arrays implicitly convert to `char*`.

If you really want to store `char*`, you can allocate the memory on heap and assign the pointer of the allocated memory to your pair. Then, of course, you have to free the memory. Or you can assign a pointer of an array allocated on the stack, but then you have to make sure the array allocated on the stack will be valid during the lifetime of the map.

As it was suggested in the comments, you can use `std::vector<char>` instead of the `std::pair<char*, std::size_t>`. Then you can even omit the explicit size of the bytes:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<char>> my_map = {
    {"key1", {0xE2, 0x82, 0xAC}}
};
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use a static-lifetime object during initialization? That is, simply replacing the inline char* with a named one? (ordering, visibility, eg.)

Comment: `static char s1[] = {0xE2, 0x82, 0xAC};` would be fine without using "the heap".

Comment: @aschepler Yep, I've changed the answer since :-)

Comment: I don't see any mention of using static storage duration.

Comment: @aschepler That's because storing the data in a static storage and storing a pointer to it in a map wouldn't be the wisest idea in this case, I think. Or is there some reason why you'd find it a good solution?

Comment: Not a very good solution, but better than using `new`, if there are a small finite number of initial arrays to populate.

Comment: @aschepler I don't know if static storage is better... Since the standard says the access to static data must be thread safe, there will always be some lock under the hood when the data is accessed. But I agree that naked `new` wouldn't be the nicest way to tackle the problem :-)

Comment: Dynamic initialization of static storage objects is automatically threadsafe, not all access. And this would be static initialization.

Comment: @aschepler Damn, you're right, and till now I was living under the impression that all the access for static objects must be thread-safe. Not that it would make any difference here, because it would be behind a pointer anyway, but at least I learned something new :-)